# Categorize my constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Is the following constraint linear?

$$\lambda_1=\alpha_1 q^2+\varepsilon$$

$\lambda$ is a 1x8760 vector which is also a decision variable.

$\alpha$ is just a number, which is also a decision variable.

$q$ is a 1x8760 vector, which is an input. This means all values in the $q$ vector is known. However all 8760 values are different.

$\varepsilon$ is an input, which is constant.

I am trying to determine if my problem is linear programming, but i am unsure as q is squared.

Comment: Please learn how to write formulas with Latex/Mathjax. I have done it for you this time.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie

Answer (score 2):

I interpret $q^2$ as element wise squaring.

Then yes, it is linear.

If it helps, you can let $q^2=p$ and every entry of $p$ is known.

Comment: Could you explain why it is linear? 

Is it because no decision variable is in the second order?
If I draw the Lambda vs. q it is shaped convex.

Comment: yes, we just care about decision variables.

Comment: Okay thanks! I have tried finding explanation online, but been unlucky. Do you know a site or book that explains this?

Comment: this is just the definition of linear programming right?

Comment: yes. But linear programming requires linear constraints, as far as I know. Maybe it is the definition of linear constraint im a unsure about.

Comment: linear constraints are of the form of $a^Tx=b$, $a$ just have to be a constant vector.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is linear.
You mention that $q$ is a known input vector. Thus, $x = q^2$ is also known and it will be a vector. 
Then you will have $ \lambda = \alpha x + \epsilon $, where basically $\alpha$ is the only parameter that you optimize.

**Note**
I have understood $x = q^2$ as a pointwise product, i.e., $x = q \odot q$.